# smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) not working in py-script

Tags: python, pyscript

I want to make a function that can send email in web.

When i running the code in python, it work.
Then i want to use the py-script to use the code.

My code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<py-script>import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

html = '''
<h1>hello</h1>
<div>這是 HTML 的內容</div>
<div style="color:red">紅色的字</div>
'''

mail = MIMEText(html, 'html', 'utf-8')   
mail['Subject']='html 的信'
mail['From']='senderEmail@gmail.com'
mail['To']='recevier@gmail.com'

smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login('senderEmail@gmail.com','password')
status = smtp.send_message(mail)
print(status)
smtp.quit()</py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it have some exception.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvewP.png)

Comment: You cannot open socket connections using pyscript

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post images (or links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted directly into the question and [formatted properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). By posting images we are not able to copy your code to reproduce it. Also, it is not searchable so others can find your question easily. For more, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6045800)

Comment: As an aside, your code seems to be written for Python 3.5 or earlier. The `email` library was overhauled in 3.6 and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical. Probably throw away what you have and start over with the [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: Pyscript seems like a really bad candidate for this because you would need to include your secret Gmail access token in the script where anyone can pick it up. The most common solution by far is to use a `mailto:` link and assume the user has a mail client set up.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am first-time to use stack overflow. 

I want to make a function that is similar to notify email. Send notification content to the user.

I don't know what to use to complete it. Is there are some simple and easy-to-use methods to recommend?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said in the comments to the original post, SMPTlib doesn't really work in PyScript/Pyodide. Though it imports, it relies on the ability to open a blocking socket, which is not currently possible. See, for instance, [this comment on a similar issue on the Pyodide repo](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/issues/2884#issuecomment-1188042547).

(This is true as of PyScript 2023.03.1/Pyodide 0.22.1. Both are evolving quickly, and there may be more options available in future versions.)